# How to name dynamically a reference in a div on Angular template inside a loop

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm developing a project using Angular 8.3.

I have a loop (using *ngFor) and I need that every div that I add has an unique reference name created dinamically).

This is my example code:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of list; let i = index;">
    <div
        cdkDropList
        #done0="cdkDropList"></div>
</div>
```

Below I have another drag and drop zone that must receive these elements:

```
<div
          cdkDropList
          #donesList="cdkDropList"
          [cdkDropListData]="DonesList"
          [cdkDropListConnectedTo]="[done0, done1]"
          class="movie-list"
          (cdkDropListDropped)="onDrop($event)">
            <div *ngFor="let itemList of DonesList" cdkDrag>{{itemList}}</div>
          </div>
```

I need to change dynamically #done0, e.g. (#done0, #done1, #done2, #done3, etc).

How can I do it? I have tryed using #done{{i}}} but it doesn't work.

I don't know if I can use trackBy in this case and how to apply it.

Many thanks,

Comment: Why do you "need" a different template variable name for each item? Most of the time (if not always), we can use the same name.

Comment: I need it because after that code in another part of the template I have another dragAndDrop zone:
```
<div
          cdkDropList
          #doneList="cdkDropList"
          [cdkDropListData]="DoneList"
          [cdkDropListConnectedTo]="[done0, done1]"
          (cdkDropListDropped)="onDrop($event)">
            <div class="movie-block" *ngFor="let donesList of DoneList" cdkDrag>{{moviesList}}</div>
          </div>
```

So I need to access to them using cdkDropList component.

Comment: Please note that the variable is defined only inside of the `ngFor` loop; that is why giving different names does not provide any benefit (and cannot be done, as far as I know). To make the elements available in other parts of the template, you can use `@ViewChildren` (with the variable defined as `#done="cdkDropList"`).

Answer (score 1):

Reference a container:

```html
<div *ngFor="let item of list; let i = index;" #doneContainer>
  <div cdkDropList></div>
</div>
```

and in .ts you have different references in a NodeList:

```
const list = this.doneContainer.childNodes
```

or in a more Angular way, which is better, as it will update when necessary:

```
@ViewChildren('doneContainer') list: QueryList<any>;
```